# Decrypt or decode using JWT& Java

Tags: java, authentication, jwt

I am trying to decrypt the token using the JWT to get the few user information.

```
String se="AEWG4RS5MmQL_ev-jgI8Zw==";
 String jwt="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjBpMW1WX2hfeVBqUXJlck9uS21mdTI4SW9MMCIsImtpZCI6IjBpMW1WX2hfeVBqUXJlck9uS21mdTI4SW9MMCJ9.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.woWtiNFp8YkRLQUGdqscpBvgAo3nkjU_zfeeBhDFAdjyIQZy1soMK_xTWRyt6anQxyGAg32zeXsi45_ROR7JpYhpbQHT7EHVbXQ4XCGRFfnhZt3MmOwOetRzzXM5d_wShvFq8qIIlE9vWXMEOsbvv8E0GOoZzN5fDxxavlw9S-zk_lKuDTVL4jiikvxT9Iv5UABOubBReNNU9ayXBGps3KHUp2X3Kxy_9fhRsWUqOlreuG914pTHOF6kKRLrmc9UY5jJ9cA7SLilRhvpjMk-ULJQEi4eGL0bnbGX8rdIii3rZBdSwsYC8UaUtMOAP6KKJpIXR699D4F5Q9kw-71Pvg";
    Claims claims=null;
    try {
        claims = Jwts.parser()              
          .setSigningKey(se)
           .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

but when i am trying to execute the code i am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures.  Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
```

can you please help me out to resolve the issue?

Comment: The token is not encryted but only signed. Check on jwt.io You just need to do Base64 decoding of the middle part between the two '.' to get your claims. Try it on base64decode.net. You would need the public key only to veryfy the signature.